# Best way to implement constantly updating map using JavaScript and websockets?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, websocket

This question is a little more general, but hard to find a good answer.

In short, I am trying to build a live Map powered by the Google Maps API, and whenever a user opens our web-app, I'd like to send a ping on a websocket channel that will instantly drop a pin on the map of their current location using the HTML5 GeoLocation API.

Currently, I have a few options. I'm ideally trying to do this without a server to conserve resource, i.e. using a protocol like WebRTC or service like [Pusher](http://pusher.com) / [httprelay.io](http://httprelay.io)

- Implement in a more p2p fashion, using a service like Pusher / HTTP Relay, but then is it possible to have a persistent connection? Or do I have to constantly poll the service? Pusher looks like it would get very expensive very fast, while HTTP relay is free, but appears 'too good to be true' especially for production
- Implement using WebRTC (?)
- Build internal API to send user coordinates to MySQL server, constantly poll server, but this seems like a waste of MySQL/Apache/bandwidth resource, if there was a way to open a persistent stream - this would make more sense
- Create Node.JS socket server, but this seems very tedious and again, involves setting up a server.

Has anyone had to work with a similar problem before, know how to do this in an efficient way?

Comment: So you want a pin to show on a map where every user is who is currently using your app and you want that map to show all the pins for all the users in all the current clients?  And you want to do this without implementing your own server?  FYI, creating a node.js server is not tedious.  It can be done in a few minutes - probably in way less time than you can figure out whether these other services you mention have enough capabilities to solve your problem.

Comment: Have a look at [Firebase realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) and [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire).